# Windows 7 System Recovery Tool, "The system image is on a hard disk, but windows needs to format..."

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Windows 7 image that I am trying to restore to. It is contained on a partition of my hard drive and I want to do the restore to a different partition as such:

D: Images
C: <-Restore to this one

I get the following message
"The system image is on a hard disk, but Windows needs to format that disk to restore your computer. Choose a different image to restore."

Has anyone had this problem before or does anyone know how to get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are picking the right partition to restore to? It would only need to format that partition, not the whole disk. How was this image made? What software? Are you doing this from a boot disc?

Comment: @Moab: This is created with the Built in Windows 7 System Recovery Tools. Yes it is the boot disk for it. As far as I know I am picking the write partition but that's all part of my question, how do you pick the partition, I get to that error message before it gives me an option to pick the partition.

Answer (score 1):

The image contains information about your whole hard drive, not just one partition. ["a system image is in essence a snapshot of an entire drive(s). The backup is done in block level (as opposed to file level) increments"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2009/10/31/learn-more-about-system-image-backup.aspx) (click the link for information on where to store your image)
Therefore, windows 7 is trying to reformat your whole hard drive to what it was when you saved the image.

I think your only option is to back up your data and move the system recovery image to an external hardrive.